# how can i add a user to UCM workflows using IDOC script?

Tags: oracle, webcenter, oracle-ucm

I'm trying to implement logic in the oracle UCM workflow, that when a document is rejected, it should add the original author to the workflow step.
I've tried the following idoc script on the entry point of the previous step but it didn't work

```
<$if wfAction like "REJECT"$>
<$trace(wfGet("originalAuthor") , "#console")$>  // this code prints and work
<$trace("#all", "#console")$>   //  this code prints and work
<$wfAddUser(wfGet("originalAuthor"), "user")$> // this
<$endif$>
```

the originalAuthor is a variable that i set in the beginning of the workflow , so i can keep track of the original authoer , if other user checked out / checked in other document .

Answer (score 0):

`wfAddUser` can only be used in a token.
If you haven't worked with workflow tokens before, have a look in the Options menu in Workflow Admin. I don't know what problem you are trying to solve, but by the looks of it, my guess is that tokens are what you are looking for.